# Loopback CLI lb-clean command not found - linux

Tags: strongloop, loopback

I have created a loopback 4 application using 'lb4 application_name' command. After running 'npm start', it shows 'lb-clean' command not found error. My node version is 16.13.2 and loopback version is 4.0.0.

Answer (score 11):

This error occurs when you try npm start before running npm install because the development dependencies are not installed after creating the app with lb4 command.

1. Create the app with lb4 application_name.
2. Run npm i
3. Run npm start

Comment: It would be nice if they put this in the documentation, hey it would be nice if one could make a pull request to change the documentation...

Comment: pull request is https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/pull/9297